# How can I group validate dynamic fields?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm currently generating an area of my form for which I want to display a custom error message if any of the generated fields are blank.

My generated code looks something like so

```
<input type="text" id="Field1" name="Generated" />
<input type="text" id="Field2" name="Generated" />
```

etc...

And my validation code is like so

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        Generated: {
            required:true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Generated: { required : "Custom message." }
    },
    groups: {
        GeneratedGroup: "Generated"
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        if (element.attr("name") == "Generated"){
            $('#bottomOfGeneratedSectionDiv').append(error);
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

If all the generated fields are blank, validation fails and the error message is displayed.
If any one of the fields is filled in, validation passes and the form submits, which is unintended behaviour.

How do I group validate dynamic fields?

**Edit**
With sparkies help and my new errorPlacement code.
This should accomplish my goal.

```
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        if (element.attr("name").indexOf("Generated") >= 0){
            $('#bottomOfGeneratedSectionDiv').empty();
            $('#bottomOfGeneratedSectionDiv').append(error);
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend using a custom selector : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749419/jquery-validate-with-custom-selectors-and-logic However I could not get it to work http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/AnhPq/

Comment: names must be unique and the syntax for adding fields to a group is wrong.  Check the groups section of the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field names **must** be unique for this plugin to function properly.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="Field1" name="Generated1" />
<input type="text" id="Field2" name="Generated2" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            Generated1: {
                required:true
            },
            Generated2: {
                required:true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Generated1: { 
                 required: "Custom message."
            },
            Generated2: { 
                 required: "Custom message."
            }
        },
        groups: {
            GeneratedGroup: "Generated1 Generated2"
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/xCY4T/**

---

To add rules to dynamically added fields, you would use [the `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) right after a field is created.  (AFAIK, there is no method for dynamically adding the `groups` option)

```
$('[name="Generated2"]').rules('add', {
    required:true,
    messages: {
        required: "Custom message."
    }
});
```

Or for many new fields at once, use the "starts with" selector and `.each`...

```
$('[name^="Generated"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required:true,
        messages: {
            required: "Custom message."
        }
    });
});
```

Simple demo of this method:  http://jsfiddle.net/xCY4T/1/

---

Another way would be to *create* a `class` using [the addClassRules method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules#namerules).

```
$.validator.addClassRules("GeneratedRule", {
    required: true
});
```

Then when you create the new fields, make sure they each contain a `class="GeneratedRule"` along with a unique `name`, of course.

```
<input type="text" name="Generated1" class="GeneratedRule" />
<input type="text" name="Generated2" class="GeneratedRule" />
```

This method is very easy but I see no way to over-ride the default messages.

Simple demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/xCY4T/2/

Comment: OK, so how would I write this for an `n` number of generated fields?

Comment: @BiffMaGriff, the code that generates the fields must make sure to create unique names and then you call the `rules('add')` method to add the rules to the new fields.  See my edits.